# Using Stream to iterate over Fibonacci Sequence in Java

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, java-stream

In class we used this code to generate a Fibonacci sequence via an Integer Stream. 
Can someone please explain to me what the .map() function is doing in this code?

```
public class fibStream {

    public static Stream<Integer> getFibStream() {
        return Stream.iterate(new Integer[] {0,1}, s -> new Integer[]{s[1], s[0] + s[1]})
              .map(s -> s[0]);  //what is .map() doing here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the java-docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Owing to the seed `new Integer[] {0,1}`, you would be iterating on `Integer[]` with two elements. Iterating with a new `Integer[]` every step with its values re-evaluated.

The `map` is just accessing the first of those `Integer` to finally consume(make use of) it.

For an example, better composed implementation of the same could look like(*print 20 first fibonacci element*) :

```
Stream.iterate(new Integer[] {0,1}, s -> new Integer[]{s[1], s[0] + s[1]})
      .limit(20) // short-circuit
      .map(s -> s[0])
      .forEach(System.out::println); // consume the mapped element
```

From the [comments by JollyJoker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062083/using-stream-to-iterate-over-fibonacci-sequence-in-java/55062167?noredirect=1#comment96872663_55062167)

> Additional clarification; the fibonacci stream is made of arrays like
>   `{0,1} {1,1} {1,2} {2,3} {3,5}` and `.map(s -> s[0])` gets each array,
>   returning the first number from them, like `0 1 1 2 3`.

Comment: By the way, do note your stream is infinite and you should use a short-circuiting operation to end it.

Comment: Thx! Your answer helped me understand this better!

Comment: it's just filtering out the first element of the Array since the return type of getFibStream() is asking for a single Integer and not an Integer[].

Comment: Additional clarification; the Fibonacci stream is made of arrays like {0,1} {1,1} {1,2} {2,3} {3,5} and `.map(s -> s[0])` gets each array, returning the first number, like 0 1 1 2 3

Comment: @JollyJoker Thanks. Can I take in that example as is to the answer?